May the sum of Wiener processes be a Wiener process?
May $X_t = W_t + \tilde{W}_t$ be a Wiener process, if $W_t, \tilde{W}_t$ are Wiener processes?
I know that:

$X_t$ may be not a Wiener process, e.g. in case $W_t = \tilde{W}_t$.

If $W_t$ and $\tilde{W}_t$ are independent then $X_t$ is not a Wiener process, because $Var W_t + Var \tilde{W}_t \ne t$. So if the answer is positive then  $W_t$ and $\tilde{W}_t$ are dependent.


I don't know if there exist dependent Wiener procesess $W_t, \tilde{W}_t$ such that $X_t = W_t + \tilde{W}_t$ is also Wiener.

Let $B_t$ and $\tilde{B}_t$ be two independent standard Wiener processes, and define $W_t$ and $\tilde{W}_t$ by
\begin{align*}
W_t &= \frac{1}{2}B_t + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \tilde{B}_t, &
\tilde{W}_t &= \frac{1}{2}B_t - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \tilde{B}_t
\end{align*}
Then it is routine to prove that both $W_t$ and $\tilde{W}_t$ are Wiener processes. Moreover,
$$ W_t + \tilde{W}_t = B_t $$
is also a Wiener process.

Do we suppose that $B_t$ and $\tilde{B}_t$ are independent? It looks like we suppose it.

@SergeiNikolaev, Oops, sorry that I forgot to mention that. Definitely yes! :)

@ Sangchul Lee Thank you very much!

@ Sangchul Lee By the way, did you know this example? Or how did you guess?

I didn't know about this specific example, but I was trained to think of "multivariate gaussian" as vectors (via Gaussian Hilbert space), so I tried to find two unit vectors whose sum is still a unit vector, and then translated that idea to gaussian's side.

@ Sangchul Lee  Very interesting!

I am surprised that a great contributor like you did not edit the answer to mention independence.

@geetha290krm, Yeah, I got distracted by something else and then this completely slipped through my mind. Thank you for reminding me of this, it is fixed now! :)
